# Jquery object caching

Tags: jquery, caching

Is this the proper way to cache an object for later use.

```
var x = $value.children().andSelf().filter('embed'),

vsrc = x.attr('src'),
vwidth = x.attr('width'),
vheight = x.attr('height');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

However, you could improve your formatting:

```
var x = $value.children().andSelf().filter('embed'),
    vsrc = x.attr('src'),
    vwidth = x.width(),
    vheight = x.height();
```

Also, you can use `width()` and `height()` to retrieve the dimensions of the element.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is exactly how to "reuse" a jQuery object if you don't want to chain it.  (Chaining can make your code hard to read if you overuse it, so this is often a good alternative.)

It's common, though not at all a standard, to give your variable a name starting with `$` to mark it as a jQuery object:

```
var $embed = $value.children().andSelf().filter('embed');
```

[(Joel on "apps hungarian" notation.)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html)

Comment: great, commas are used to add other variables without the need to use var again

Comment: What do you mean by semicolons rather then commas?

Comment: @Šime — I swear the other variable assignments weren't there when I wrote that.  :-)